# Avoid switching between tabs

Tags: aem

I have a panel with radio button options to select a panel to display. Below is the listener that I am using on `selectionchange`.

```
function(box, value) {

     box.findParentByType('tabpanel').manageTabs(value);
     console.log(value);

}
```

Here I have two panels, the console.log statement displays "panel1", "panel2" when the event occurs, but also automatically switches to the selected panel — I want to just make the selected panel visible rather than switching to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, I guess you are trying to use the `manageTabs()` function defined in the foundation list component to achieve this.

If that is the case, then the manageTabs takes in 2 arguments.

1. The value which you are passing
2. A boolean value to tell whether to switch tabs are not.

Hence, changing your code to the following should do the job.

```
function(box, value) {
     box.findParentByType('tabpanel').manageTabs(value, true);
     console.log(value);
}
```

You can find the `manageTabs()` function defined here `/libs/foundation/components/list/dialog`